# How to map URL that does not contain the {controller} to a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

I am very familiar with URL routing in Web Forms and have a basic understanding of MVC routing but have ran into a scenario I am not sure how to wire up. I want to map the a URLs that do not contain the `{controller}` in the URL map to a controller.

I want to map the following URLS to the controller "SectionHomePageController"

```
Books/{Action}
Cinema{Action}
Collections/{Action}
Games/{Action}
```

I know the typical way of a route would be {controller}/{action} so I am not really sure how to wire up these URLs to a controller. So how do I wire up these URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map a route (should be above your regular `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route so it takes precedence) that has a constraint and defaults to your `SectionHomePageController`:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SectionHomePage",
            url: "{prefix}/{action}",
            constraints: new { prefix = @"(Books|Cinema|Collections|Games)" },
            defaults: new { controller = "SectionHomePageController", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Note that you now won't be-able to have a BooksController, CinemaController etc as this route will override the default one.

Comment: Thanks, that looks to be working perfectly. I got confused by the defaults keyword thinking that was what the controller and action would be if there was none passed in URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "SomeRoute",                                              // Route name
                "Collections/SomeAction",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "SectionHomePageController", action = "SomeActionOnController", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```